# AppleScript Bounds moves app from current monitor

Tags: applescript

I record a lot of videos, so I have a MacBook Pro with two monitors connected. One of those monitors has a resolution set to 1920x1080. I record all my videos from that specific monitor. Right now, I run Google Chrome and Visual Studio Code. Then, I resize the windows for the specific conditions of my recording (sometimes Chrome uses more space, sometimes VSC does), so this is not a matter of simply doing a side-by-side setup where each app takes up a certain percentage.

That manual process is tedious and I usually want them to be a very specific size based on what I am recording. That is why I want to use AppleScript to simply resize the currently running applications based on various recording scenarios.

To create a test case, I wrote the following code. While it does the trick of perfectly resizing the app, it moves Chrome from the monitor I am recording on to my MacBook Pro's connected display.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
set theApp to "Google Chrome"
set xLocation to 0
set yLocation to 0
set appWidth to 750
set appHeight to 1080


tell application "Google Chrome"
    set bounds of front window to {0, 0, appWidth, appHeight}
end tell
```

Unfortunately, I am very new to AppleScript and have not been able to figure out how to prevent the script from moving the app (Google Chrome in this case) from the current monitor to the MacBook Pro monitor. I suspect it is that `front window` code, but I am struggling to learn how that works as I cannot find the documentation.

How can I use AppleScript to resize an application that is currently running without moving the application's window to another monitor?

I suppose if the answer is to open a new copy of the application, that would work too, so long as I can open or move it to the proper monitor. Thanks!

**Update**
Close, but not quite there...
I was provided [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168926/run-applescript-for-specific-monitor) in the comments. The code looks like this:

```
set theScreens to paragraphs of (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType -detailLevel |grep \"Resolution:\" | awk -F\"Resolution: \" '{print $2}'")
set theMonitor to ""
log theScreens

set the counter to count of theScreens --- set to 1 if you want to test it on monitor 1
if (counter) > 1 then
    -- we will do things for monitor 2
    set thisDisplayWidthHeightMonitor_2 to {(word 1 of item 1 of theScreens) + 2, 0, ((word 1 of item 1 of theScreens) + (word 1 of item 2 of theScreens)), word 3 of item 2 of theScreens}
    set theMonitor to thisDisplayWidthHeightMonitor_2
else
    -- we will do things for monitor 1
    set thisDisplayWidthHeightMonitor_1 to {0, 0, (word 1 of item 1 of theScreens), (word 3 of item 1 of theScreens)}
    set theMonitor to thisDisplayWidthHeightMonitor_1
end if

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://netflix.com"}
    
    set bounds of window 1 to theMonitor
    log theMonitor
    
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
    end tell
end tell
```

If I log the variable `theScreens`, I get the following result:

```
(*3072 x 1920 Retina, 3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition), 4608 x 2592*)
```

That code does not show me the correct `x` position I need for my window placement. It just shows the monitors I am using and their UHD resolution.

When the code opens Safari (in this case), it sets the bounds with the variable `theMonitor`, and it does indeed open in the monitor I want it to. The output is:

```
3074, 0, 6912, 2160
```

Since the code does display the application in the monitor I want, I assume that 3074 is the correct x position for my need, so here is my updated code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set bounds of front window to {3074, 0, 750, 1080}
end tell
```

Unfortunately, Google Chrome completely disappears off the screen and is nowhere to be found on any monitors or desktops. I have to quit Chrome and restart so I can use it again (or do the change the change-the-screen-resolution trick).

I am still left with the following question: How do I open the app in the correct monitor I desire and in the x & y location I desire?

Comment: `0,0` is the top left of the main monitor. So your code moves the window so that its top left is at the top left corner of the main monitor. To write your script, you need to know where the monitors are, in "world" coordinates. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168926/run-applescript-for-specific-monitor for example.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it does not really answer the question. It gets so far as to open an application window in a monitor at full screen. Unfortunately, it does not explain how to set the **x** position or the **width**. Instead, it uses a bunch of `word` and `item` values that I do not fully understand and create a large number (not a readable `bounds` array. Can you lend some insight as to how to address my question?

Comment: I don't agree. I ran the first line of the suggested solution `set theScreens to paragraphs of (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType -detailLevel |grep \"Resolution:\" | awk -F\"Resolution: \" '{print $2}'")` and got exactly the information you need, i.e. where the monitors are.

Comment: Hi Matt, I completely agree that the code locates where the monitors are, but my question is "How can I use AppleScript to resize an application that is currently running without moving the application's window to another monitor?". Using the code you are sharing, maybe I can get set the Bounds starting at the correct x coordinate, but from what I see it is just telling me what monitor uses the 1920x1080 location, not the correct bounds. Maybe I am missing something? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Well you can see what monitor it is on by looking at what the bounds of the window are _now_ and comparing that to the bounds of the monitors. So now if you resize / reposition the window, keep it in the monitor it's one now. That was the problem, as I understand it.

Comment: The bounds command only takes x, y, width, height. The code you link to shows me what monitors are available. I still do not know what to type for `x` that would say, place it in the correct monitor.

Comment: Why don't you know? It's the `x` for the monitor that contains the window. Look, if I tell you that you have two tiny monitors, one at `0,0,100,100` and another at `100,0,100,100`, and that you have a window at `110,10,30,30`, which monitor is it on? Don't tell me you don't know the answer; you do know the answer. So teach your program how to know the answer. That is what programming is: it's telling a machine how to think like you.